# Find the volume below the surface $z=x^2+y^2$ above the plane $z=0$ and inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2y$.

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

> Find the volume below the surface $z=x^2+y^2$, above the plane $z=0$ and inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2y$.

I'm getting the answer as :
$$
2\int_{0}^{2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}(x^2+y^2)dxdy
$$
but I'm not able to solve this integral. Using various tools on the internet, I found the answer to be $\frac{3\pi}{4}$. 
But the answer given is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try doing it the integral by converting to polar coordinates.

Comment: In terms of $(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z)$?

Comment: Could you show the steps leading to your answer?

Comment: $\pi/2$ is not the correct answer. Change to cylindrical coordinates $(x, y, z) = (r \cos t, 1 + r \sin t, z)$.

Comment: @Vishnu: I believe you should get something like: $$V=\int_{-1}^1{\int_{1-\sqrt(1-x^2)}^1 {\int_0^{x^2+y^2} {1}\mathrm{d}z} \mathrm{d}y}\mathrm{d}x + \int_{-1}^1{\int_1^{1+\sqrt(1-x^2)} {\int_0^{x^2+y^2} {1}\mathrm{d}z} \mathrm{d}y}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$$